# Find and differences between -perm /6000 and -perm /u+s

Tags: permissions, files, find

I have been trying to find setuid executables using a `one liner'.

The line I first tried was:

```
find / -perm /u+s -type f
```

Then I found a line which is similar but gives different results:

```
find / -perm /6000 -type f
```

These look identical as far as I can tell, but the first one doesn't show as many results as the second one (mostly ones with weird groups are missing). Why, what is different?

Comment: AFAIK, a leading 6--- for `chmod` sets both the setuid and setgid bits on a file, so you get this permission configuration as a result:

`---S--S--- 1 cumin cumin    0 Oct  2 04:52 test`

The three zeros following the 6 demarcate no read, write permissions for any and no execution permissions for the other group. Are you wondering why the results differ?

Comment: Heh, I feel kindof foolish now. I realized this early this morning. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most people aren't aware but the Unix permissions are actually not just User, Group, and Others (rwx). These 3 triads are the typical permissions that allow users, groups, and other users access to files & directories. However there is also a group of bits that precede the User bits. These bits are referred to as "Special Modes".

It's more of a shorthand notation that you don't have to explicitly set them when dealing with a tool such as `chmod`.

```
$ chmod 644
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
$ chmod 0644
```

Here's the list of bits:

*excerpt wikipedia article titled: [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Special_modes)*

```
Flag                Octal value     Purpose
----                -----------     -------
S_ISUID             04000           Set user ID on execution
S_ISGID             02000           Set group ID on execution
S_ISVTX             01000           Sticky bit
S_IRUSR, S_IREAD    00400           Read by owner
S_IWUSR, S_IWRITE   00200           Write by owner
S_IXUSR, S_IEXEC    00100           Execute/search by owner
S_IRGRP             00040           Read by group
S_IWGRP             00020           Write by group
S_IXGRP             00010           Execute/search by group
S_IROTH             00004           Read by others
S_IWOTH             00002           Write by others
S_IXOTH             00001           Execute/search by others
```

#### Your Question

So in your first command you're looking for `u+s`, which would work out to be bit `04000`. When you use the numeric notation you're asking for bits `04000` *AND* `02000`.  This would give you files with user or group setuid bits set.

#### Further Reading

I highly suggest anyone that wants to understand the permissions better in Unix, to read the [Wikipedia page about `chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). It breaks it down very simply and is a excellent reference when you forget.

#### References

- [chmod Tutorial](http://catcode.com/teachmod/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Mode `6000` is `u+s,g+s`, not just `u+s` (that would be `4000`).

`find / -perm /u+s` or `find / -perm /4000` only finds files that have the setuid bit set. `find / -perm /u+s` or `find / -perm /6000` finds files that have the setuid bit set or the setgid bit set.